# will the following JAPE rule override the existing annotation or add an extra annotation?

Tags: information-retrieval, gate, information-extraction

Below JAPE rule will replace the Email annotation by Address or just add an extra annotation Address ?

```
Rule: EmailFinal
Priority: 50
(
{Email}
)
:address
-->
:address.Address = {kind = "email", rule = "EmailFinal"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `:label.Type = {...}` will always create a new annotation, but it won't touch the existing ones. If you want to delete the input annotation then you need to add a second action to your rule:

```
Rule: EmailFinal
Priority: 50
(
{Email}
)
:address
-->
:address.Address = {kind = "email", rule = "EmailFinal"},
:address { inputAS.removeAll(addressAnnots); }
```

Comment: Wau `inputAS.removeAll(addressAnnots);` is a great shortcut for the old way using `bindings`.

Comment: @dedek yes, labelled blocks `:label { ... }` are a handy shorthand - it gives you an automatic variable `labelAnnots` inside the block equivalent to `bindings.get("label")`, _and_ the block is guaranteed to run only in cases where that set is not empty.